# Allocate struct from function in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm having issues writing a function that allocates a struct in C. Ideally, I want to have the function fill the fields of the struct with parameters passed into it.

I have defined the struct in my header file like so:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[NAME_SIZE]; //Employee name
  int birthyear; //Employee birthyear
  int startyear; //Employee start year
} Employee;
```

And this is what I have for my function currently:

```
void make_employee(char _name, int birth_year, int start_year) {
  Employee _name  = {_name,birth_year,start_year}; //allocates struct with name
} /* end make_employee function */
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could describe a little more on how this function will be used and what you want to do with the created struct.  How you allocate memory and create data structures in C depends greatly on how you are planning on using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return a pointer allocated via malloc:

```
Employee* new_employee(char *_name, int birth_year, int start_year) {
    struct Employee* ret = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    ret->name = _name;
    ret->birth_year = birth_year;
    ret->start_year = start_year;
    return ret;
}
```

two more things: (1) you should make the struct definition of name a `char*` instead of `char[NAME_SIZE]`. Allocating a char array makes the struct much bigger and less flexible. All you really need is a `char*` anyway. And (2) change the function definition to `char*`.

Comment: I don't know about the advice you are giving for point (1)... As long as `NAME_SIZE` is a reasonable size, it's not really worth it doing it right - dynamically allocating the memory and having to manage it.  No need to complicate it any more than necessary.

Comment: If keeping things simple is important to you, then you know what to do. However, allocating 200 bytes to something that only needs 5 is overkill (and allocating 5 to something that needs 6 is a bug) - hence why you might want to go with the pointer

Comment: Make sure you `free` the structure after you're done with it, or else you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 11):

The problem with your current code is that the struct your creating is created on the stack and will be cleaned up as soon as the function returns.

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct foo* create_foo( int a, int b )
{
    struct foo* newFoo = (struct foo*)malloc( sizeof( struct foo ) );
    if( newFoo )
    {
        newFoo->a = a;
        newFoo->b = b;
    }
    return newFoo;
}
```

This will get you a heap allocated object. Of course, you'll need a function to free that memory or this is a memory leak.

```
void destroy_foo( struct foo* obj )
{
    if( obj )
        free( obj );
}

void print_foo( struct foo* obj )
{
    if( obj )
    {
        printf("foo->a = %d\n",obj->a);
        printf("foo->b = %d\n",obj->b);
    }
}
```

(btw, this style gets you part of the way toward an "object oriented" C. Add some function pointers to the struct (to get polymorphic behavior) and you have something interesting; though I'd argue for C++ at that point.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Employee * make_employee(char *_name, int birth_year, int start_year)
{
    Employee *employee;

    if (employee = (struct Employee *)memalloc(sizeof(Employee)) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(&(employee->name), _name);
        employee->birthyear = birth_year;
        employee->startyear = start_year;
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Why does the make Employee return void? You need to return the Employee from the make_employee function!
2. Are you having trouble with the compiler complaining about the `x = {a,...}` syntax? Write it the long way then: `Emp e; e.field1 = a; ...`
3. Are you having weird overwriting / bogus numbers problems? If you allocate a struct in the function it will become invalid (and prone to being overwriten) as soon as the function returns! To go around this you either have to:

   - Return a copy of the struct (this is OK for small structs):

     ```
     Employee make_emp(int a){
         Emp emp; //Allocate temporary struct
         emp.filed1 = a; //Initialize fields;
         return emp; // Return a copy
     }
     ```
   - Allocate the struct in the heap instead and deal with it through references (ie.: pointers) instead:

     ```
      Employee* make_emp(int a){
         Emp* emp = malloc(sizeof(Emp)); //Allocate the struct on the heap
                                         //And get a reference to it
         emp->filed1 = a; //Initialize it
         return emp; //Return the reference
      }
     ```

     Don't forget to `free()` the Employee after you are done with it in this case!